# Compiling GLib for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, c, glib

Can GLib be compiled for iOS? If not, what other alternatives are there?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225233/glib-use-in-an-iphone-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191599/how-to-use-glib-on-iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to build glib for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638594/how-to-build-glib-for-ios)

Comment: Sorry for that @JosephQuinsey.

Answer (score 2):

If/when you manage to build it, you won't be allowed to use it in a retail application because of LGPL.  [Here](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/lgpl-and-the-iphone.html) you can find some pretty clear argumentation on this.

Though there are alternative points of view on LGPL vs iOS deal.  If you in favor of those, then at very least you'd be required to provide object (.o) files of all of your code upon request.

So please be careful.  Evaluate if you could actually use it, before you rush off hacking and trying to build it.

Comment: I am not so sure that argument is valid. If having to pay for the development environment disqualifies it, that would rule out use with most commercial compilers. That is hardly the intent of the LGPL.

Comment: The authors of GStreamer seem to have no problems with LGPL on iOS. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674960

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, it can be built](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733328). There are several Apps in the Appstore that uses it.